# What is the difference between static int a and int a?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between 'global'  and 'static global'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959889/difference-between-global-and-static-global)

What is the difference between statements 1 and 2 :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
//In the global declaration area 

static int a; // 1.
int b;        // 2.
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [Difference between 'global'  and 'static global'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959889/difference-between-global-and-static-global)

Comment: Aside from all answers given, it is worth mentioning that all static variables, no matter where they are allocated, as well as all global variables (like "b" above), are subject to "static initialization". This means that they must be initialized by the program before it starts. Thus, you are guaranteed by the standard that they are initialized. If you haven't initialized them explicitly, they are implicitly initialized to zero (or NULL for pointers). This makes them different from local scope variables as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `static` global variable is local to the [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) it is defined in. So, if you define `static int a;` in two different translation units, this will create two independent variables. If you define a non-static global variable `int b;` in two translation units, you will experience a linker error (but you can use `extern int b;` in one of the two translation units to tell the linker that it should use the global variable from the other translation unit).

Answer (score 7):

Both are variable definitions, however, the `static` keyword applied to a variable in the "global declaration area" restricts that global variable to be seen only in the *translation unit* in which it is defined.

Comment: In other words, if it's in the file `foo.c`, then `bar.c` won't be able to access it, even if you `extern` it.

Comment: @EboMike +1, thanks for the further clarification

Answer (score 4):

They are both in memory for the entire lifetime of the program. The variable that is declared static only has scope in the file in which it is declared where as the variable declared without static can be accessed from other files using an extern declaration.

Original source - http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/860211-global-variable-static-global-variable

Comment: This answer is the most complete one provided.

Answer (score 2):

`static int a` is only accessible within that file. `int b` can be accessed with `extern int b` from a different file.

Comment: To be pedantic, if you define `static int a` in a header file, it won't be accessible "within that file" ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
static int a; 
int b;
```

`a` has internal linkage. `b` has extern linkage.

C99 `6.2.2`

> 6.2.2  Linkages of identiﬁers
>
> - 1)      An  identiﬁer  declared  in  different  scopes  or  in  the  same  scope  more  than  once  can  be
>     made  to  refer  to  the  same  object  or  function  by  a  process  called linkage.  There  are
>     three kinds of linkage: external, internal, and none.
> - 2) In  the  set  of  translation  units  and  libraries  that  constitutes  an  entire  program,  each
>     declaration  of  a  particular  identiﬁer  with external  linkage  denotes  the  same  object  or
>     function.   Within  one  translation  unit,  each  declaration  of  an  identiﬁer  with  internal
>     linkage denotes  the  same  object  or  function.  Each  declaration  of  an  identiﬁer  with no
>     linkage denotes a unique entity.
> - 3)  If the declaration of a ﬁle scope identiﬁer for an object or a function **contains the storage-
>     class speciﬁer static, the identiﬁer has internal linkage**.

Comment: You are assuming they are both allocated at file scope. If they were allocated locally, your statement wouldn't be true. The static would still have internal linkage, but the non-static would be allocated with "automatic" linkage, i.e on the stack or in a CPU register.

Comment: @Lundin : "You are assuming they are both allocated at file scope"

Check out the question again.

Answer (score 1):

A static variable's life extends across the lifetime of the program. However, scope rules still apply.

If you define your static variable outside of a method (normally at the beginning of the class) your variable will be available from anywhere within that class.

You can't change the value of these objects. They're normally used for storing things like API keys.